# Mensagem de popover em uma div

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, popover

Bom dia. Eu tenho uma div que ao ser clicada, abre uma página. Até aí tudo bem e está funcionando.

Agora como que eu faço para que quando o usuário passar o mouse sobre essa DIV, aparecer um popover com a mensagem "Para editar clique aqui".

Meu código está assim:

```
<div class="card-body card-padding container editar">
     meu conteudo xxxxxxxxxxxx
</div>
```

Quando clico nessa div, tenho um javascript que abre a página que quero:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
       document.querySelector('.editar').onclick = function(){
    window.location = 'http://minhapagina.com';
}
        });
</script>
```

Me desculpem a pergunta boba... como faço para quando passar o mouse, aparecer o popover?

Grata

Comment: Amanda eu te dei uma resposta usando o componente padrão do Bootstrap3 que está na tag da sua pergunta. Mas existem formas de fazer só com CSS também no :hover do elemento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como vc botou nas tag da pergunta Bootstrao 3 vou considerar que vc está usando ele.

O Boostrap 3 tem esse componente de forma nativa. Não precisa adicionar nada de mais para fazer funcionar. Aqui tem a documentação. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips-examples

**Aqui tem um exemplo prático usado na documentação.** *Dentro do `title=" "` do elemento vc coloca o seu texto.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    body {
        margin: 40px;
    }
div.btn {
    background-color: red !important;
    background-image: none;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>

<div class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="hover na div">isso é uma div</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>


    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Repare que vc precisa apenas "iniciar" o `popover` com esse script e usar as `classes` da documentação.

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```